# IllegalStateException on Alertdialog and ButterKnife

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, butterknife

I'm new On android and I want to use butterknife on my code. In my practice i have a FAB button in main activity layout:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:onClick="addURL"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    app:fabSize="normal" />
```

after click on my FAB , An alertDialog is appeared .there is a Textedit view in the dialog custom layout:

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_add_url"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

this is my onclick:

```
   public void addURL(View view) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Add your URL:");
    ButterKnife.setDebug(true);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            addURLToList();
        }
    });
```

and :

```
    private void addURLToList() {
    editTextAddURL.setText("Hi");

}
```

I get editText_add_url reference like a field:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@BindView(R.id.editText_add_url)
EditText editTextAddURL;
```

After running I got this error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.manifest.simplefiledownloadmanager/com.example.manifest.simplefiledownloadmanager.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'editText_add_url' with ID 2131558531 for field 'editTextAddURL' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' (fields) or '@Optional' (methods) annotation.
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'editText_add_url' with ID 2131558531 for field 'editTextAddURL' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' (fields) or '@Optional' (methods) annotation.
                                                                                              at butterknife.internal.Utils.findRequiredView(Utils.java:92)
                                                                                              at butterknife.internal.Utils.findRequiredViewAsType(Utils.java:104)
                                                                                              at com.example.manifest.simplefiledownloadmanager.MainActivity_ViewBinding.<init>(MainActivity_ViewBinding.java:27)
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                                                                                              at butterknife.ButterKnife.createBinding(ButterKnife.java:199)
                                                                                              at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:124)
                                                                                              at com.example.manifest.simplefiledownloadmanager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
                                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
                                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039) 
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I know my mistake is because of butterKnife deceleration but I don't know how can I use Butterknife on alertdialog with custom layout.
thanks guys.

Edit ------------
this is my oncreate method:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    initView();
}
   private void initView() {
    //set Toolbar to Activity
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //set Fragment
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frameLayout_container,
            new ListDownloadFragment()).commit();


}

public void addURL(View view) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Add your URL:");
    ButterKnife.setDebug(true);
    ButterKnife.bind(MainActivity.this, view);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            addURLToList();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    View inflate = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_url, null);
    builder.setView(inflate);
    dialog = builder.show();
}

private void addURLToList() {
    editTextAddURL.setText("Hi");

}
```

Comment: where did you inflated your view ?

Comment: please post your onCreate method since the crash is happening there

Comment: from where you calling "addURL" method?

Comment: i think EditText(editText_add_url)  is not a child of view which you are passing in addURL method.

Comment: @DamianJäger i have edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

When calling ButterKnife.bind() in onCreate() ButterKnife tries to bind all @BindView annotated views from the current layout. R.layout.activity_main, however, does not contain a view with the id R.id.editText_add_url. Therefore it crashes.

I generally recommend using ButterKnife only for the main view of a class and calling findViewById to find views for dialogs and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a private class to bind views of dialog layout inside your fragment, like this.

```
//To bind with the dialog view using butterKnife
public class DialogViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.editText_add_url)
    EditText editTextAddURL;

    DialogViewHolder(View view) {
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }
}
public DialogViewHolder dialogViewHolder;
```

Then in addUrl function you can use it like,

```
View inflate = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.dialog_add_url, null);
dialogViewHolder = new DialogViewHolder(inflate);
```

And it should do the trick.